# Is there a way to use --esModuleInterop in tsconfig as opposed to it being a flag?

Tags: typescript

Typescript v 2.7 released really neat flag called `--esModuleInterop` https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html, I am trying to figure out if there is a way to use it with `tsconfig.json` as currently it doesn't seem to be documented : http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html

Unless it somehow works with `module?`

Main use case I want to achieve is to be able to import things like this

`import React from "react"`

as opposed to

`import * as React from "react"`

And do so from my tsconfig if possible

Answer (score 81, accepted):

Yes, do `"esModuleInterop": true` in your tsconfig.json. For every flag option that can be passed to the CLI, the same can usually be done this way in the config file. Doing `tsc --init` on the command line generates a tsconfig full of comments explaining all of the available options.

---

EDIT: I've learned that the behavior of `esModuleInterop` is dependent on what is set to `module`.

If you have `"module": "commonjs"`, you only need to enable `"esModuleInterop": true`.

If you have `"module": "es2015"` or `"module": "esnext"`, you also have to enable `"allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true` in order to import CommonJS modules (like React) as a default.

Comment: It works for me using combination of `"module: "es7"` and `"moduleResolution": "node"` alongside the flag. There are issues with `@types/react` not being updated for this yet though.

Answer (score 3):

**I have also faced the same issue,**

- This issue is specific to typescript version
- Perform below steps to remove it ( It worked for me)

1. In your project, inside package.json file - verify that you have typescript under the dependencies
   devDependencies{
   "typescript": "^2.5.2"
   }
2. check the installed version of the typescript on your system by typing tsc -version command in terminal

- this will show the installed version of typescript at global level
- o/p version - 2.9.1

3. Change version number insider package.json file with the version installed on your system.

devDependencies{
"typescript": "^2.9.1"
}

**Hope this will work!!!!!!!!!!!!**

Comment: Thanks! That was the issue. `npm i typescript --save` worked for me