# typescript: namespace import + specific import

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

the problem I try to solve

`import * as React from 'react';
import {Component} from 'react';`

I dont like it being two lines - to be frank it is not even allowed by my linter settings.

But writing the following

`import * as React from 'react';
const Component = React.Component;`

doesnt look fine to me as welll - as I willl have llines of imports and than const delarations - which are actually imports

in a non TS syntax the above lines could have been

`import React, {Component} from 'react';`

and this is what I am looking for, but

`import * as React, {Component} from 'react';`

is not a valid syntax.

The question

how can I acchieve a one liner with namespace import and partial import

Comment: Have you tried `import * as React from 'react'` and then `class A extends React.Component {}`

Comment: @Aaqib good though - that would work - but I mean more of a general example

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Starting from TypeScript 2.7, you can enable `esModuleInterop` in your `tsconfig.json` to enable `import React, { component } from 'react'`

There is a specific meaning for `import * as React from 'react'`, which is getting the module namespace object of the module `react`.
As it gets everything in the module, it is more natural to use `React.component` then extracting `component` using the `import { component } from 'react'` in addition.

Comment: it did the job  - specifically with React there is a small issue - that this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48785451/is-there-a-way-to-use-esmoduleinterop-in-tsconfig-as-opposed-to-it-being-a-fla topic helped to resolve