# error TS1192: Module @types/lodash/index has no default export

Tags: angular, lodash

I'm using `Angular 6.x.x` in my project with the following `lodash` dependency.

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "6.0.9",
    "@angular/core": "6.0.9",
    ...
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.114",
    ...
  },
```

Both of the following import are not working for me.

```
import _ from 'lodash';  

import * as _ from 'lodash';
```

Comment: if you this (import * as _ from 'lodash';) are you getting any error

Comment: not only *@types/lodash* you have to add *lodash* to your *package.json* as well

Comment: Did my answer help? Did you fix your issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems like the following import was working perfectly fine. I had issues with my environment. After deleting the `node_modules` directory and installing it, it worked.

```
import * as _ from 'lodash';
```

Comment: You are awesome !

Comment: If this is used in typescript project, above method fails after compiling

Answer (score 3):

### Brief

The solution is to:

1. Add `{"esModuleInterop": true}` to your `.tsconfig`
2. Make sure you have installed `"@types/lodash"`in your `devDependencies`

---

### Reasoning

In short: 
*Typescript has a different default `import` mechanism compare to ES6 default.*

For examples, you can import a function from a module either by:

1. Import as a whole:

   ```
   import _ from 'lodash';
   const results = _.uniq([1, 1, 2, 3]);
   ```
2. Import just a part:

   ```
   import {uniq} from 'lodash';
   const results = _.uniq([1, 1, 2, 3]);
   ```

However, in Typescript it gives you some syntax sugar for `2. Import a part`, which looks like this:

```
// This is valid in Typescript
import uniq from 'lodash';
const results = _.uniq([1, 1, 2, 3]);
```

Which is nice but makes `1 Import as a whole` not inferrable. By adding `esModuleInterop` it can make the default ES6 behavior work again.

More details was mentioned here in another thread:
[Is there a way to use --esModuleInterop in tsconfig as opposed to it being a flag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48785451/is-there-a-way-to-use-esmoduleinterop-in-tsconfig-as-opposed-to-it-being-a-fla)

Answer (score 1):

You need to install the lodash library.

"@types/lodash" are the lodash type definitions which are required to use lodash with typescript.

To install lodash run:

```
npm i --save lodash
```

in a terminal.